# Как вывести данные из БД без скобок и построчно?

Tags: sql, кортежи

Подскажите как вывести кортеж из БД без скобок и построчно?

```
qwestion=cur.execute('SELECT * FROM qwestions').fetchall()
    for qwestion_list in qwestion:
         print(qwestion_list)
```

#Выводит :

```
(1, 'Первый вопрос')
(2, 'Второй вопрос')
(3, 'Третий вопрос')
(4, 'Четвертый вопрос')
```

А надо :

```
1, Первый вопрос
2, Второй вопрос
3, Третий вопрос
4, Четвертый вопрос
```

Усложнение еще в том что переодически количество вопросов будет меняться, ну и сами вопросы по смыслу будут меняться.

Comment: Чуть исправил заголовок, чтобы при поиске не сбивал других.

Comment: Скобки добавляет кто угодно, только не SQL сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю примерно так, как ниже. Не зависит от количества вопросов и текста. Адаптируйте это к вашему `cur.execute`.
Пытаться сделать короче не стал - так яснее всего, полагаю.

И для информации - нет в БД кортежей. Это вам `cur.execute` в таком виде даёт данные оттуда.

```
question_list = [(1, 'Первый вопрос'), (2, 'Второй вопрос'),\ 
                (3, 'Третий вопрос'), (4, 'Четвертый вопрос')]

for question in question_list:
    for i in question:
        print (i, ' ', end = "")
    print ('\n') # Убрать эту строку, если надо вообще все в одну строку выводить
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! 

Comment: Андрей, комментарий выше прочитайте:-)

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: ответ примите  (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).. Это не голос и он должен работать у вас..